# NgWebDriver waitForAngularRequestsToFinish() is not working

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to implement NgWebDriver using Selenium Java for angular app.

As per NgWebDriver [documentation](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) we have to only pass `new NgWebDriver(driver).waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();` driver instance but when I am trying to implement it , I have to cast argument to JavascriptExecutor otherwise its giving error in the syntax.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
NgWebDriver ngdriver = new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor) d);
ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
```

When I use this code after casting driver instance as than its not waiting for angular to finish.

Repeater & other functions are working fine of NgWebDriver .

Can anyone please help in in resolving the problem?

Using these versions:

```
Selenium: 3.3.1
Chrome: 60
Java : 1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing this?

```
d.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
```

instead use the

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

then use the following

```
NgWebDriver ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
```